# XML parsing having siblings with same name

Tags: java, json, xml

I have an XML like this and have to parse this and need to print the elements is a table format on UI or if i will get the JSON then also i can do something.

But i am not able to fetch all the elements of XML because `<type>` tag has been used multiple times.

```
<catalog>
<product productsname="Choclates">
    <Parameters total="2">
        <Subtype name="dairy milk">
            <type>oreo</type>
            <type>Silk</type>
            <type>nuts</type>
        </Subtype>
        <Subtype name="Other">
            <type>perk</type>
            <type>kitkat</type>
            <type>5 start</type>
        </Subtype>
    </Parameters>
</product>
<product productsname="Biscuits">
    <Parameters total="3">
        <Subtype name="parle">
            <type>parle G</type>
            <type>krack jack</type>
            <type>monaco</type>
        </Subtype>
        <Subtype name="britannia">
            <type>good day</type>
            <type>50 50</type>
            <type>bourbon</type>
            <type>tiger</type>
        </Subtype>
        <Subtype name="Priya Gold">
            <type>Italiano Cookies</type>
            <type>Glucose V</type>
            <type>Butter Bite</type>
            <type>CNC</type>
            <type>Marie Lite</type>
            <type>Classic Cream</type>
        </Subtype>
    </Parameters>
</product>
```

I have tried DOC parser.

Comment: This is a nice case for **JAXB** with annotations, with as one field a List of types. At most two lines to load the XML.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using jdom2 library :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        org.jdom2.Document jdomDoc;         
        try {   
            jdomDoc = useDOMParser(new File("your_xml_file"));              
            List<Element> products = jdomDoc.getRootElement().getChildren("product");           
            for (Element product : products) {
                System.out.println("----" + product.getAttributeValue("productsname"));
                List<Element> subtypes = product.getChild("Parameters").getChildren("Subtype");
                for (Element subtype : subtypes) {
                    System.out.println("--" + subtype.getAttributeValue("name"));
                    List<Element> types = subtype.getChildren("type");
                    for (Element type : types) {
                        System.out.println(type.getText());
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}                
    }

    private static org.jdom2.Document useDOMParser(File fileName)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbFactory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fileName);
        DOMBuilder domBuilder = new DOMBuilder();
        return domBuilder.build(doc);

    }   
}
```

The above produces the below output :

> ```
> ----Choclates
> --dairy milk
> oreo
> Silk
> nuts
> --Other
> perk
> kitkat
> 5 start
> ----Biscuits
> --parle
> parle G
> krack jack
> monaco
> --britannia
> good day
> 50 50
> bourbon
> tiger
> --Priya Gold
> Italiano Cookies
> Glucose V
> Butter Bite
> CNC
> Marie Lite
> Classic Cream
> ```

Comment: facing difficulty to change this into an object, if we will write this logic in rest call and pass productname as parameter , then it should return all details of that product.  But i am not able to convert it into object. please help.

Comment: just create a Product class with appropriate fields/data structure, eg containing a List of subtypes, and each subtype containing a List of types. Then as you parse the XML create and populate each Product object as needed.